# In .NET, when are getter and setters called?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a button object that uses this model class.

```
public class ButtonModel {
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public Image Icon {get; set}
    public Color BackgroundColor {get; set;}

    public ButtonModel(string name, Color color) {
        Name = name;
        Icon = Image.FromFile(AssetsFolder + "/" + Name);
        BackgroundColor = color;
    }
}
```

I load up all of the ButtonModels at the start, but I'm thinking that this might hurt performance. Is there a significant difference between the class above and this:

```
public class ButtonModel {
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public Color BackgroundColor {get; set;}
   public Image Icon {get { return Image.FromFile(AssetsFolder + "/" + Name); }}
}
```

More specifically, is the getter for Icon called when the class is first initialized, or is it called when the Icon property itself is used? Based on experience with getters before, the second statement seems more right. Furthermore, does the Image in the Icon property (assuming its not used elsewhere) stay  in memory, or is it freshly reset everytime the property gets called?

Comment: The first class declaration has a bug, it forgets to implement IDisposable.  The second class can't do that, it is somebody else's job to dispose the image.  Without any cue that they need to every single time they use the property.  Yes, big difference.

Comment: Wouldn't the GC collect managed objects after they have been used? I haven't seen any memory usage increase after startup.

Comment: _"Wouldn't the GC collect managed objects after they have been used?"_ -- the GC _might_ collect the object, if it winds up unreachable. The `Image` class objects have finalizers that will take care of disposing the object before it's collected, but that's a backstop, not something good code relies on. You should always ensure an object has been disposed when you no longer need it. Of course, in your first example, it's possible that the model object itself is never discarded, and so the `Icon` value also never needs to be disposed. There's not enough context to say for sure.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, right now ButtonModel acts as a helper class for filling in a bunch of Images in the desktop app. The reason why I asked this question is because many buttons aren't loaded directly on startup, but are loaded when other WPF UserControls get built. In this case, isn't the mild performance penalty of reading from disk better than keeping the object in memory?

EDIT: I've looked at the IDisposable bug from above. Immediate disposal did reduce the heap by 20MB, from 100MB idle. GC right now starts around 180MB during heavy usage and peaks at 240MB, then to idle.

Comment: _"isn't the mild performance penalty of reading from disk better than keeping the object in memory?"_ -- that would depend on a number of factors, including how much RAM and swap file space is available to you, how fast your disk is, how big the files are, etc. Beyond immediate init and lazy init (the example in my answer completely precludes ever being able to discard individual images...the entire model object would have to be released), there is also caching, which can be implemented with or without weak references. Memory management is a very broad topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is the getter for Icon called when the class is first initialized, or is it called when the Icon property itself is used? Based on experience with getters before, the second statement seems more right.

The getter is called *every time* that any other code uses the property name in an expression where the property value is needed. I.e. "the second statement".

> Furthermore, does the Image in the Icon property (assuming its not used elsewhere) stay in memory, or is it freshly reset everytime the property gets called?

This depends on what `Image` is. But assuming you're talking about `System.Drawing.Image`, it doesn't do any internal global caching. Every time you call `FromFile()`, it's going to read the file and create a new object instance.

So, no…you probably do not want to use the second code example you provided, because it's going to have to recreate the image object every time the property is used.

That said, in *some* cases you may find that the [`Lazy<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.lazy-1) class is useful. E.g.:

```cs
private readonly Lazy<Image> _icon = new Lazy<Image>(() => Image.FromFile(AssetsFolder + "/" + Name));

public Image Icon => _icon.Value;
```

Whether this is helpful depends on whether the property value is always used immediately when the program starts or is only retrieved later. If the property value is always used immediately, then you are unlikely to see much if any advantage by using `Lazy<T>` (it could in fact even be slower). But for a property that is only used sometimes, and it's acceptable to make the user wait for the initialization at the instant it's going to be used, the `Lazy<T>` class can provide that functionality for you.

*Aside: I have been remiss in failing to mention the related issue that [Hans brings up in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64508782/in-net-when-are-getter-and-setters-called/64508843#comment114066245_64508782). Specifically, the code you posted doesn't show any mechanism for correctly disposing the `Image` object that was created. That's a whole other topic for discussion, and it's entirely possible that your code example was simplified for the sake of the question. But just make sure you do take a look at the requirements for dealing with objects that implement `IDisposable`.*